# How to calculate the latitude of the subsolar point (ie. solar declination) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, astronomy

I am trying to calculate the point on Earth where the sun is directly overhead using javascript. My function for longitude works great, but I am having trouble with the latitude.

I understand that what I am looking for is called the Solar Declination, and an approximate formula for that is [(source)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/solar-declination):

δ=23.45 * sin[(360/365)(284+N)]

where N is the day in the year, where January 1 is 1, Feb 1 is 32, etc.

This is the function I am using now:

```
    function getSolarDeclination(){
        return -23.44 * Math.sin( (360 / 365.25) * getDayOfYear() )
    }

    function getDayOfYear(){
        var now = new Date();
        var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
        var diff = now - start;
        var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        var dayOfYear = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
        return dayOfYear + 284
    }
```

However, this doesn't seem to be giving me the right number. For today, June 3, 2020, I am getting 17.607657911890687, whereas at least according to [this site](https://stevemorse.org/jcal/dms.html) it should be ~22.465. This is several hundred miles off!

What am I doing wrong? Is this approximate formula just too "approximate"?

Comment: Just so you know, your approximation might reasonably work for that year, but if you want more precision there is the [alternative calculation of the equation of time on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time#Alternative_calculation) that you can use to get the equation of time (which corrects the longitude via an offset in minutes) and derive the declination (which yields the latitude) for the subsolar point. These all depend on varying moments like the perihelion and December solstice dates for the year, and even on varying values for eccentricity, obliquity for longer periods.

Comment: You should, for clarity's sake and for helping others, also include your function for longitude that works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the formula you're using expects values in degrees, but `Math.sin` uses radians. If you convert it, it gives roughly the expected result:

```js
function getSolarDeclination(){
    return -23.44 * Math.sin( (360 / 365.25) * getDayOfYear() * Math.PI/180 )
}

function getDayOfYear(){
    var now = new Date();
    var start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    var diff = now - start;
    var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var dayOfYear = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
    return dayOfYear + 284
}
    
console.log(getSolarDeclination())
```

Comment: That's it! maybe only a few miles off, which is good enough for my purposes. Thank you!